# Was the adjective 'Soviet' more commonly used than 'Russian' during the cold war?

Tags: history, politics

Watching 'The Crown' made me wonder whether the usage of 'Russian' is anachronistic in the show. I.e. whether common usage in the UK and the USA would have been 'Soviet Tanks' or 'the Soviets' when referring to armed conflict and political intrigue. Does anyone have any evidence for that from newspaper clippings or official transcript? One example I found supporting my hypothesis was the NY Times headlines "... Kennedy ready for Soviet Showdown" from the Cuban missile crisis.

Comment: Usage guidelines. https://www.quora.com/Is-it-inaccurate-to-use-the-terms-Russian-and-Soviet-interchangeably-given-the-other-countries-that-comprised-the-U-S-S-R

Comment: With such a nice question, you need to learn how to use google's ngram viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: I almost always used Soviet or USSR during the Cold War.

Comment: The Soviet Union comprised 15 countries previously independent--the Soviet Socialist Republics.  Russia was the main one, and leaders of the U.S.S.R. came primarily from there, although Stalin was born in Georgia (one of the 15).  They are not interchangeable.  Each is appropriate in different uses.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, adjective describes you!

Comment: In the UK the Soviet Union was often referred to as simply "Russia" especially in the tabloid press.

Comment: Russia was the dominant component of the Soviet Union in every respect, and the successor state to a land known as "Russia," so it's quite unsurprising to me that you would find the one substituted for the other even in sources like the *New York Times* or *Time*, especially in headlines. Compare at *Turkey* for the *Ottoman Empire*, or the British use of *Holland* to refer to the Netherlands, or the American use of *England* to refer to the UK.

Comment: Strictly speaking they are not the same thing. The Soviet Union was comprised of many republics, only one of which was Russia. Two categories of people might have used Russia when meaning the USSR - the less educated/uninformed e.g. @MichaelHarvey's tabloid readers, and also older people who had a perspective of pre-Soviet Russia. People like Churchill and de Gaulle would use "Russia", since their ideas were partly informed by "the age of empire" and  19th-century diplomacy.

Comment: @choster Your comments are spot on.  The use of Google ngrams is totally inappropriate here.  Moreover, political writers were often quite careful to distinguish between *Soviet*, to describe the current (and presumably changeable) government, and *Russian* to describe the land and the people.  A sophisticated writer like George Kennan would use the terms very precisely, knowing that his readers would understand what he was referring to.  Kennan was U.S. Ambassador to the USSR at one point, and I'd hardly call him "older" or "less educated/uninformed".

Comment: @Global Charm. George Kennan was certainly not of the tabloid-reading class. But he was born in 1904, and his basic education completed before the term USSR had become established parlance.

Comment: Using "Russia" in preference to "USSR" or "Soviet Union" was also employed as a political tool to minimise the importance of communist ideology to their foreign policy. The country was seen by many as exhibiting a political continuation from its time as Tsarist Empire - so it could still be thought of as Russia. Charles de Gaulle's use is a particular example of this. To the French President it was still old Russia.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not about the English language and its usage.

Comment: President Ronald Raegan famously (and jokingly) announced he was outlawing Russia and would start bombing in minutes. The original quote: [*"My fellow Americans, I'm pleased to tell you today that I've signed legislation that will outlaw Russia forever. We begin bombing in five minutes."* (click for the audio tape)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_begin_bombing_in_five_minutes).

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that a modern rendition of past events would substitute Russians for Soviets. I'm not even sure that qualifies as an anachronism. Certainly late in the cold war in America, *Soviets* predominated among the military when used in the context of "the enemy." But earlier on, *Russians* may well have been used out of habit, or as a way to downplay the legitimacy of the USSR. For a corpus of contemporary documents, try [here](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1961-1968/cuban-missile-crisis)

Comment: I believe *Russia* was used very often by people when speaking, while the more accurate *Soviet* would have been used more often in writing, especially in situations where accuracy was considered important, like journalism.

Answer (score 1):

I did searches in the [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) and concluded that both phrasings were used often enough in America during the Cold War, with "soviet tank" being more common (depending on the year). The searches are as follows:

`soviet tank*`:

[image]

`russian tank*`:

[image]

---

I repeated the searches in the [Time Magazine Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/time/) and although the graphs are slightly different, the conclusion is the same: both were used but "soviet tank" was more common.

`soviet tank*`:

[image]

`russian tank*`:

[image]

---

In these searches, `tank*` matches any word that starts with tank, such as "tank", "tanks", or "tankers". You can repeat these searches yourself by creating a free account [here](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/), then using the ["chart" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4V4r.png) to search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it answers your question the way you wanted, but I got this:

The Soviet Union was a federal socialist state in Eurasia that existed from 1922 to 1991. So also in the Cold War. The countries we now know as Moldova, Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, Russia, Armenia, Azerbaijan, Georgia, and Ukraine were all ONE country together back in the Cold War; the Soviet Union.

You can compare it to the United States, it was ONE country, with different states. And one of the 'states' was Russia, the biggest and most important one. So unless you want to specifically say something came from Russia I think 'Soviet Union' was more commonly in the Cold War.

After all, you say an American tank comes from America. It was made in one of the states but you don't mention the specific state it came from, saying it's from America is enough.

So in that year Soviet Tank is likely more common.

I hope this answers your question.